# How extension $\Bbb{Q}_p(\hat{E}[p])/\Bbb{Q}_p$ looks like?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, p-adic-numbers

Let $E/ \Bbb{Q}_p$ be an elliptic curve over $ \Bbb{Q}_p$. $\hat{E}$ denote the corresponding formal group of $E$.
I want to know what
$\Bbb{Q}_p(\hat{E}[p])/\Bbb{Q}_p$ is .

At first I tried to prove  $\hat{E}$ is Lubin Tate formal group, but it wasn't.
I might be missing some basic approach to this problem.

P.S
At first I wrote it is degree $p-1$ extension, but Chris Wuthrich pointed out that it does not hold in general(when $E$ is super singular, it is true), and I edited.

Comment: That edit made my comment absurd, so I delete it.

Comment: Sorry to bother ,but could you tell me why $[p]t＝0,t≠0$ implies extension degree is a divisor of $p-1$(Where did you used the condition, $E$ is super singular at $p$ ?)

Comment: The equation $[p](t) = 0$ defines you the extension. You can factor the power series as $t\cdot f(t) \cdot u$ with $f$ a polynomial and $u$ a unit. Sagemath can calculate that easily.

Comment: I don't still get why 'super singular or not' relates this problem.

Comment: If $E$ has good ordinary reduction, then $f(t)$ is a polynomial of degree $p-1$. The action of the absolute Galois group on $\hat E[p]$, which is cyclic of order $p$, gives a character and the the fixed field of the kernel is that extension defined by irreducible factors of $f$. So the degree divides $p-1$. If $p>2$ it cannot factor into linear terms as the formal group cannot have rational points.

Comment: If $E$ has supersingular reduction, then $f(t)$ is of degree $p^2$. Indeed $\hat E [p]= E[p]$ as all $p$-torsion points lie in the kernel of reduction.

Comment: I suggest you read more on the formal group of elliptic curves. Section 1.11 in Serre's "Propriétés galoisiennes des points d'ordre fini des courbes elliptiques" is a good read.

Comment: Sorry in the supersingular case it is degree $p^2-1$ not $p^2$.

Comment: Your P.S. is wrong. I did not say that it holds for supersingular curves.